# RestTemplate getForEntity method undefined

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to build a project in Eclipse Luna and encounter an error on several lines in the Test class that reference getForEntity, e.g.:

```
verify(mockRestTemplate,times(1)).getForEntity(any(), eq(String.class));
```

mockRestTemplate is defined as a variable of class RestTemplate, and I have imported:

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

I get the error in Eclipse:

> The method getForEntity(Object, Class) is undefined for the
>   type RestTemplate

This code does not cause an error for colleagues using the same project, so I suspect it is something local to my environment.

Many thanks,
Keith.

Comment: Well, what's the signature of getForEntity()? What's the type of its first argument? Is it Object?

Comment: Compile your program with Java 8 or parameterize the call to `any`, `Mockito.<String>any()` (or `URI` if that's the overload you wanted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide explicit argument type rather than use `any()`. Try to change the code depending on the actual expectation.

```
verify(mockRestTemplate,times(1)).getForEntity(any(String.class), eq(String.class));

verify(mockRestTemplate,times(1)).getForEntity(any(URI.class), eq(String.class));
```

Comment: I changed to any(URI.class) and this worked, many thanks. Why the original version only caused an error on my machine, and not on colleagues', remains unexplained, but the amended code works for all of us.